# Trying to do custom listview but it has error when I try to connect with database

Tags: android, mysql, listview, httprequest, android-arrayadapter

I have been searching about how to bring data from mysql and show them with custom listview. Now, I found a problem with Http request. Could anyone please help me check this code? I cannot find out why my code cannot work.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Mall> arrayOfMallData = new ArrayList<Mall>();

    class Mall{
        public String Mall_title;
        public String Mall_desc;
    }

    FancyAdapter fancyAdapter = null;
    static ArrayList<String> resultRow;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    try{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String result = "";

        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/BasicPHP/getJSON.php");
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();

            try {

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }

                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        try {

            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++) {
                JSONObject f = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                Mall resultRow = new Mall();

                resultRow.Mall_title = f.getString("Mall_Name");    
                resultRow.Mall_desc = f.getString("Mall_Business_Hours");

                arrayOfMallData.add(resultRow);              
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());     
        }


        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        fancyAdapter = new FancyAdapter();
        listView.setAdapter(fancyAdapter); 

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error In Code: " + e.toString());
    }
}

class FancyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Mall> {
    FancyAdapter() {
        super(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayOfMallData);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.malllist_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.populateFrom(arrayOfMallData.get(position));
        return(convertView);
    }
}

class ViewHolder {
    public TextView title = null;
    public TextView desc = null;

    ViewHolder(View row) {
        title = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.title);
        desc = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.desc);
    }

    void populateFrom(Mall r) {
        title.setText(r.Mall_title);
        desc.setText(r.Mall_desc);

    }
}  
}
```

This is my LogCat

```
05-16 15:36:53.334: I/dalvikvm(539): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-16 15:36:53.384: I/dalvikvm(539): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-16 15:36:53.494: E/log_tag(539): Error in http connection android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-16 15:36:53.494: E/log_tag(539): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
05-16 15:36:53.594: D/libEGL(539): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
05-16 15:36:53.614: D/libEGL(539): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
05-16 15:36:53.634: D/(539): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x1dee68, tid 539
05-16 15:36:53.654: D/libEGL(539): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
05-16 15:36:53.665: D/libEGL(539): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
05-16 15:36:53.726: W/EGL_emulation(539): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-16 15:36:53.744: D/OpenGLRenderer(539): Enabling debug mode 0
05-16 15:36:53.854: I/dalvikvm(539): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-16 15:36:53.875: I/dalvikvm(539): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: you are getting error NEtworkOnMainThreadException, it means you can not do network task on main thread, you have to create a new thread by unsing ( thread, async task etc... )

Comment: I don't know how to fix that one. please help ><

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html check this link.

Comment: Check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 2):

In the method `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` which is on main thread you are doing some web calls, this is the cause of the problem, you are not allowed to do this `HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);` on the main thread. Move the networking part on a different thread. Take a look at this [AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

Answer (score 0):

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. Run your code in AsyncTask. Like

```
private class RetriveJson extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
                   //retrive your data via url from here
        }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return json;
    }

}
```

and call this task at where you want like

new RetriveJson().execute("your url");

I hope this will help you.